# Strange user named "Other…" on 10.6

Tags: snow-leopard, user-account

Recently, I tried logging out of my machine (rather than just shutting it down) and I noticed that a user with the name "Other ..." was present. I don't recall adding the user. I tried checking out System Preferences >> Accounts and it just lists a disabled "Guest" account and my main account.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Other" is not a user. It just allows you to enter a username and password into textboxes instead of clicking on an icon.

It can be used to connect to a network domain user. It can also be used for special users, such as "Root" (which gives you unlimited control over all hidden and restricted files) and ">console" (which logs into your Mac in command-line-only mode.)

Comment: I see. However, I dont recall seeing this when I first installed my machine; are there settings to turn this particular display on and off?

Comment: Check out post #8 on this site: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1166153.